# Multi-kills in Dota2

Tags: dota-2

There appear to be some names for in-game multi kills. "Double Kill" and "Triple Kill" are self explanatory. Can somebody explain what are the numbers behind others, namely: "Ultra Kill" and "Rampage"? Also, I'm not really sure but there appear to be also names for killstreaks. In particular, "Godlike" is supposedly a name for a killstreak (again, I'm not sure how many kills you need to get this) rather than just another multi-kill name. Can somebody provide a comprehensive list here or at least pointer to such one?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Number of kills in a short time span (multi-kills):**

- Double kill - 2 kills
- Triple kill - 3 kills
- Ultra kill - 4 kills
- Rampage - 5 kills and above

**Number of kills without dying (streaks):**

- Killing Spree - 3 kills
- Dominating - 4 kills
- Mega Kill - 5 kills
- Unstoppable - 6 kills
- Wicked Sick - 7 kills
- Monster kill - 8 kills
- Godlike - 9 kills
- Beyond Godlike - 10 kills and above

  - For all the streaks, the announcer says what the banner reads. But for Beyond Godlike, the announcer says, "Holy Shit!", but the banner reads 'Beyond Godlike'.
  - For Monster Kill, the announcer actually says 'Ma-Ma-Ma-Monster Kill'.

**Other:**

- Ownage - 5 or more kills in a row by one team without them losing any heroes.

The origin of this style of naming kill-streaks comes from [Unreal Tournament](http://unreal.wikia.com/wiki/Unreal_Tournament#Achievements).

Comment: I would add the "Ownage!" sound to the list, too! It triggers when a team kills more than 5 enemy heroes in a row without losing any (even if not in the same teamfight).

Comment: @Vereos Good point, added it to the list.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the mega kill is for short span. Also it is Double kill->Multi kill->Mega kill->Ultra kill

Comment: @MarioStoilov Nope, it's correct as is. The sound clips can sound mixed as typically a number of kills in a short span will also increase your kill streak.

Comment: @turbo Well in Unreal Tournament (were the original announcer is from) they were like that. Must have changed them in dota...

Comment: @MarioStoilov Yes most likely, these existed in the WC3 version so the meanings were probably altered slightly to not be as direct of a rip off.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the "short time span" is a maximum of around 18 seconds between kills to maintain the streak.

Comment: it`s more fun if you have GLaDOS announcer voice :P

Comment: @NamikazeSheena Indeed XD "what your're doing is wrong" -Favorite Line. So Good!

Comment: @SMILIECHICKEN "Roshan has been callously butchered by the Radiant.
I'll put in a request to notify his children that they're orphans now. " :v

Comment: @NamikazeSheena D: Thats awful! Poor Roshan, I wish there was something we could do... * Starts arranging for charity towards starting up roshan's cheese business *